# The "intersection property" of the symmetric difference metric

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, terminology, proof-verification

$\newcommand{\measure}{\operatorname{measure}}$

The symmetric difference between sets can be used to define a pseudo-metric on the set of subsets of a given measure space:

$$d(S,T)=\measure(S\oplus T)$$

This pseudometric has the following property, that can be called "Intersection Property":

**If $S$ intersects $T$, then there is a constant $r>0$ such that
every set $S'$ with $d(S',S)<r$ intersects every set $T'$ with $d(T',T)<r$** [where "$S$ intersects $T$" means: $d(S\cap T, \phi)>0$].

Proof: Define $r = d(S\cap T, \phi)/3 = \measure(S\cap T)/3$. By assumption $r>0$. The set $S\cap T$ can be decomposed as follows:

$$S\cap T = $$
$$[(S\setminus S')\cap(T\setminus T')] \cup $$
$$[(S\cap S')\cap(T\setminus T')] \cup $$
$$[(S\setminus S')\cap(T\cap T')] \cup $$
$$[(S\cap S')\cap(T\cap T')]$$

By definition, $S\oplus S' = (S\setminus S')\cup (S'\setminus S)$. Hence:

$$\measure(S\setminus S')\leq \measure(S\oplus S') < r$$

Simlarly:

$$\measure(T\setminus T')\leq \measure(T\oplus T') < r$$

Substituting in the decomposition of $S\cap T = $ gives:

$$\measure[(S\cap S')\cap(T\cap T')] > \measure[S\cap T] - 3r > 0$$

This implies that $S$ intersects $S'$ and $T$ intersects $T'$.

My questions are:

A. Is this proof correct?

B. Is there a formal term for this property of pseudo-metrics, which I called "intersection property"?

NOTE: This property is not true for all pseudo-metrics. For example, [it is not true for the pseudo-metric based on the Hausdorff distance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732850/hausdorff-distance-and-intersection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A. Almost correct.  At the end you say that $\text{measure}[S\cap T]-3r>0$, but actually it equals zero.  Also at the end, you conclude that $S$ intersects $S'$ and $T$ intersects $T'$, but that's not what you're trying to prove: what you want is that $S'$ intersects $T'$.  Happily, this also follows from the previous line.

B. I don't know of a standard term for this property.  It does, however, follow from the intersection operation being (jointly) continuous at $S\cap T$, which is a pretty standard property.  The property I mean here is that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that for any sets $S'$ and $T'$ satisfying $d(S,S')<\delta$ and $d(T,T')<\delta$, we have $d(S\cap T,S'\cap T')<\epsilon$.  This holds for the symmetric difference metric; in fact,
$$ d_\oplus(S\cap T,S'\cap T') \le d_\oplus(S,S')+d_\oplus(T,T') $$

As for the Hausdorff metric, here are a few related results:

1. Intersection is "upper semicontinuous" for nonempty closed and bounded sets in a metric space.  Precisely: if $A,A',B,B_n$ are nonempty closed and bounded sets in a metric space $X$, and $B_n\to B$ in Hausdorff metric, and $B_n\cap A=A'$ for all $n$, then $B\cap A\supseteq A'$.
2. The inclusion in part 1 may be strict: for example, take $X=\mathbb{R}$, $A=\{0,1\}$, $A'=\{1\}$, and $B_n=\{\frac1n,1\}$.
3. Intersection is jointly continuous for closed convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$, at points where the intersection has interior.  Precisely: if $K,K_n,L,L_n$ are closed convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$, and $K_n\to K$ and $L_n\to L$ in Hausdorff metric, and $\text{int}(K\cap L)\ne\varnothing$, then $K_n\cap L_n\to K\cap L$.

Comment: (in #2, you probably meant $A'=\{1\}$?)

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi I sure did!  Fixing it now, thanks.

Comment: About #3: can you give reference? I would like to check whether this fact can be generalized for some families of non-convex sets.

Comment: I don't have a reference, unfortunately, and the proof I know depends heavily on convexity.  I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: I changed my mind.  See Theorem 1.8.8 in Schneider's *Convex Bodies: The Brunn–Minkowski Theory*.  (Actually, it looks like his statement is a bit stronger than mine, since it allows the limit sets to be not full-dimensional.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.